# lowest bound of the maximal eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory

if A is the adjacency matrix, I have to prove that $\lambda_1 \ge \sqrt{d_1}$ where, $\lambda_1$ is the maximal eigenvalue, and $d_1$ the maximal degree of the graph.

I cannot find a simple way to proove this. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result only applies to connected undirected graphs (i.e., the adjacency matrix is symmetric).  The proof is as follows.

Let $v$ be the right eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda_1$.  By the Perron-Frobenius theorem, it must be positive.  For any node $i$,
$$ \lambda_1^2 v_i = \left( A^2 v \right)_i = \sum_{j, k} A_{ij} A_{jk} v_k $$

Now consider the sum on the right hand side.  Split it into terms where $k = i$ and terms where $k \ne i$, then drop the latter.  All of the terms are positive, so we get
$$ \lambda_1^2 v_i \ge \sum_j A_{ij} A_{ji} v_i $$
Now $v_i$ can be pulled out of the sum, and $A_{ij} A_{ji} = A_{ij}$ since $A$ is symmetric and only contains zeroes and ones.  So we get
$$ \lambda_1^2 v_i \ge v_i \sum_j A_{ij} = d_i v_i $$
where $d_i$ is the degree of node $i$.  For a non-connected graph, it is not clear whether we can divide out $v_i$, because it might be zero, but for a connected graph then it must be positive.  So we get
$$ \lambda_1^2 \ge d_i $$
for any node $i$.  If we assume without loss of generality that node 1 has the largest degree, then we get
$$ \lambda_1 \ge \sqrt{d_1} $$
as desired.